# No database selected in php?

Tags: php, database, pagination

i am working and new to php i am getting no database selected error;
here is the my code which is dd.php

```
 <?php
      include('database.php');    //include of  db config file
      $pdo = Database::connect();
      $per_page = 2;         // number of results to show per page
      $sql = 'SELECT * FROM customers ORDER BY id DESC';
      $result=mysql_query($sql) or die("ERROR".mysql_error()."*****".$sql);
      $total_results = mysql_num_rows($sql);
      $total_pages = ceil($total_results / $per_page);//total pages we going to have

           //-------------if page is setcheck------------------//
            if (isset($_GET['page'])) {
            $show_page = $_GET['page'];             //it will telles the current page
               if ($show_page > 0 && $show_page <= $total_pages) {
               $start = ($show_page - 1) * $per_page;
               $end = $start + $per_page;
               } else {
              // error - show first set of results
              $start = 0;              
              $end = $per_page;
               }
             } else {
                 // if page isn't set, show first set of results
               $start = 0;
               $end = $per_page;
              }
              // display pagination
               $page = intval($_GET['page']);
               $tpages=$total_pages;
               if ($page <= 0)
               $page = 1;
            ?>
```

fix error in this code one after another i am getting new error like mysql_num_rows() error ODBC@localhost acess denied????
plz help me out??

here is my database.php

```
    <?php
       class Database
        {
           private static $dbName = 'crud_tutorial' ;
           private static $dbHost = 'localhost' ;
           private static $dbUsername = 'root';
           private static $dbUserPassword = '';

           private static $cont  = null;

           public function __construct() {
           die('Init function is not allowed');
         }

        public static function connect()
         {
           // One connection through whole application
           if ( null == self::$cont )
            {     
               try
                  {
                                                                               {
      self::$cont =  new PDO( "mysql:host=".self::$dbHost.";"."dbname=".self::$dbName, self::$dbUsername, self::$dbUserPassword); 
                   }
                catch(PDOException $e){
                die($e->getMessage()); 
                  }
                }
                    return self::$cont;
                  }

                public static function disconnect()
                   {
                   self::$cont = null;
                   }
                   }
                 ?>
```

Comment: if needed i give database.php code also

Comment: Are you using a MySQL database in the backend? cuz if so, then there's really no need to do it the way you have approached. It's really very simple and the code for that is available throughout the internet. You can take Shubham's link as an example.

Comment: Yes sir i am using xampp

Comment: `private static $dbUserPassword = '';` your password is empty or what?? **And my question is* you made connection in `PDO` and `$sql = 'SELECT * FROM customers ORDER BY id DESC';
      $result=mysql_query($sql) or die("ERROR".mysql_error()."*****".$sql);
      $total_results = mysql_num_rows($sql);
` **My_SQL**

Comment: its empty i have not set any password

Comment: mysql_* is deprecated.. please use mysqli_*

Comment: Now i got my answer problem is due to mysql_* is deprecated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

problem is due to mysql_* is deprecated replacing with mysqli_ works